# Why are 1 Timothy, 2 Timothy, and Titus referred to as the “Pastoral Epistles”?

Tags: terminology, paul-apostle, epistles

Why are 1 Timothy, 2 Timothy, and Titus referred to as the “Pastoral Epistles”?

Comment: Greetings, Long Distance Runner; while this is a good basis for a question on this site, you may want to consider part b) of your question. ‘Are there any denominations of Christianity that do not....’ You should either scope this clause to a particular Christian faith, or consider removing it. This question can be easily answered on this site; my opinion.

Comment: Isn't Titus considered an apocryphal book?  Is it considered Deuterocanonical for the Catholic Church or Orthodox Church?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All three of those letters are written by Paul to people who he mentored in the faith and are now leaders of churches (pastors) in their own right. They also deal largely with instructions and advice  relevant to church leaders - i.e. with 'pastoral' matters. That is why they are called Pastoral Epistles.

The name is not doctrinal matter - it is simply a convenient name for a group of similar letters. As such no denomination either enforces or rejects the label. People use the name if they want, and if it's convenient.